# How does cosx = sinx equals to tan x = 1

Tags: trigonometry, circles

So how does cos(x)=sin(x) can be rearranged to be tan(x)=1

Comment: So what is your definition of $\tan x$?

Comment: If $\sin(x)=\cos(x)$ then both of them are non-zero. So you just divide both sides of this equation by $\cos(x)$ and you get $\tan(x) = 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide by cos(x) on both sides.

If cos(x) is not zero, or equivalently, if x in not an odd integral multiple of pi/2,
sin(x)/cos(x) equals tan(x), and hence from your equations, tan(x)=1.

Comment: ${sin(45)=cos(45) = {1/\sqrt 2}}$  gives ${tan(x)=1}$

Comment: @SSA Yes, it does. What's your point?